# How do I clone a hard drive that is in use?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Linux server on a virtual machine with virtualbox, but would like to copy to backup while in use, because I can not stop to be giving various services.

I have seen the snapshots, but I see I saved only serve as the particular state and not the entire hard drive.

any ideas?

Comment: you could copy the .vdi file but there is no telling if it will be useful and not corrupt later on , The only safe way to back up a VM is to shut it down (not suspend) and then copy the VM folder.

Comment: You can not make a reliable copy of the entire drive while it is in use. I suggest you derive an alternate backup strategy or bring the server down while you make a backup.

Comment: If you use a copy-on-write system (LVM/btrfs) then you can create a snapshot and copy the snapshot. It violate the write sync guarantees required for atomic database operations but otherwise is reasonably safe for normal usage. btrfs actually supports [incremental remote backups](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup) and there are similar [tools](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/lvmsync/) for lvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **There is no safe way to backup a virtual hard drive attached to a running virtual machine in Virtual Box.**

Adapted from [this thread in the Virtual Box Forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=48807) we have the following backup options:

Recommended:

- Shutdown the guest and backup all files
  **Advantage:** Safe and fully recoverable.
  **Disadvantage:** Downtime from shutdown/reboot.

Alternatives if data are not critical:

- Backup files from within the guest.
  **Advantage:** Fairly safe, no downtime.
  **Disadvantage:** Needs external backup solution running on the guest. Not all applications can be backed up by this.
- Save the machine's state, backup all files, restart the guest
  **Advantage:** Fairly safe, downtime may be much shorter than a reboot.
  **Disadvantage:** needs similar hardware to recover. Some application data may become inconsistent.

Not recommended

- Take a snapshot then copy files
  **Advantage:** Very fast, no downtime
  **Disadvantage:** Not safe, may lead to inconsistencies. Backup copies may not be recoverable on another host machine. Application data may get lost.
- Just backup the files of a running manchine
  **Advantages:** none
  **Disadvantages:** disk image corruption may lead to unusable backups.

Comment: An option I'm missing here is: 1) Take the guest down. 2) Take a VM snapshot. 3) Back up the snapshot and control files. 4) Bring the guest up. 5) Back up the virtual disk(s). 6) Once you won't need to restore from this backup: delete the snapshot. Won't this be safe? It substantially reduces downtime.